# How to use React Component in Visual Studio

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn React, but I have to use Visual Studio.  I had it all working until I tried to move my "Hello World!" into a component.  Since import and export do not work, I do not know what to do.

Here is my component code:

```
export class MyApp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

The file name is MyApp.js.  I am trying to render it in app.tsx like so:

```
declare var require: any

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');


ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Of course `<MyApp />` shows an error, but `import MyApp from "./MyApp"` throws an error as well.  How do I call the component?

Someone asked for a "stack trace" on error.  Here is output of Build when attempting to use `import MyApp from './MyApp.js';`:

```
------ Build started: Project: React 3, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
    > react-3@0.0.0 build C:\Users\Beryl\Source\repos\React 3
    > webpack-cli app.tsx --config webpack-config.js
    Hash: 3fb246caf6d3cb4b2e4b
    Version: webpack 4.42.0
    Time: 2534ms
    Built at: 03/11/2020 10:18:41 AM
                  Asset      Size  Chunks                   Chunk Names
        ./app-bundle.js   946 KiB    main  [emitted]        main
    ./app-bundle.js.map  1.08 MiB    main  [emitted] [dev]  main
    Entrypoint main = ./app-bundle.js ./app-bundle.js.map
    [./MyApp.js] 326 bytes {main} [built] [failed] [1 error]
    [./app.tsx] 287 bytes {main} [built]
        + 11 hidden modules
    ERROR in ./MyApp.js 4:12
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:12)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
    |     render() {
    |         return (
    >             <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    |         );
    |     }
     @ ./app.tsx 5:17-38
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 2
    npm ERR! react-3@0.0.0 build: `webpack-cli app.tsx --config webpack-config.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 2
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the react-3@0.0.0 build script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Beryl\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-

11T15_18_41_360Z-debug.log
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Node.js Tools\Microsoft.NodejsToolsV2.targets(60,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm run build" exited with code 2.
Done building project "React 3.njsproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

Here is my webpack-config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
devtool: 'source-map',
entry: "./app.tsx",
mode: "development",
output: {
    filename: "./app-bundle.js"
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.Webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx', '.tsx']
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts|\.tsx$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: {
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            }
        }
    ]
}
};
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Was the project started with create react app? If so, export and import should work.

Comment: Is that Visual Studio error or React compiler error?

Comment: @DBS the error on <MyApp /> says "cannot find MyApp".  using "import MyApp" produces tons of error messages in the output as the project will not compile.

Comment: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/370 same issue

Answer (score 0):

try to just declare your class

```
class MyApp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

And at the end of the file use
`export default MyApp;`

In your app.component use import statement

`import MyApp from './MyApp'`;

Then

`ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById('root'));`

Also if you are importing `js` file into `tsx` file you need to specifi the file extension in import statement.

`import MyApp from './MyApp.js'`

Comment: Thanks, but that does not answer my question.  How do I import the component?

Comment: This "import MyApp from "${./MyApp}" throws an error as well "cannot find module "${./MyApp}".  This a app.tsx is a file in Visual Studio.  I'm not sure how jQuery plays into this, but it is all new to me.  Also if you read my question, I already said that this "import MyApp from './MyApp.js'" does not work.  It throws 252 errors The comand "npm run build" exited with code 2, Missing JSDoc @returns for function plus 250 more errors.

Comment: Did you create your app using `create-react-app`?

Comment: And u said that that  `import MyApp from './MyApp'` does not work, but i recommended you to use path with file extension, its huge different in the following example

Comment: it doesn't work with the extention either.  I tried it both ways.